# Three dimensional static array memory allocation

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, malloc

I am new to C++ programming, you might think its silly question but I tried everything. I want to allocate a memory using malloc for three dimensional array.

I dont want to use pointers. I want size to be fixed.

```
float xyz[60000][28][28];

xyz = (float ***) malloc(60000 * sizeof(float ***));
for(int i=0;  i<60000;  i++)
    {
        xyz[i]=(float **)malloc(28 * sizeof(float *));

        for(int j=0;  j<28;  j++)
        {
            xyz[i][j]=(float *)malloc(28 * sizeof(float));
        }
    }
```

I tried above code, but its giving me error. Incompatible types.

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You can't do anything dynamically unless you use pointers. The way you are trying to do things does not work.

Comment: If you're using C++, why not take advantage of containers like vectors and arrays?

Comment: There are a lot of things you can do. This just isn't one of them. The reason your code doesn't work is that you have an `=` and on the left hand side you can have a variable of type `float[60000][28][28]` so on the right you'd have to have the *value* of a variable of that type, which you don't. You can't use `=` to move `xyz` to a different place in memory.

Comment: float xyz[60000][28][28]; already allocates memory for the array

Comment: The usual: A pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer. `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` ftw.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What you would suggest the solution?

Comment: @xaxxon does it mean that, its already on hip memory?

Comment: *I want to allocate a memory using `malloc()` for three dimensional array.* – Why??

Comment: @Swordfish I am writing CUDA programming(learning). I need to pass the reference of the array for cudamalloc

Comment: `float xyz[60000][28][28];` allocated quite a bit of storage, but be cautious with  it. That's something close to 200 MB of storage. If that's a local variable on the stack, the program has almost certainly overflowed the stack.

Comment: @SachinBankar [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068410/allocating-a-large-memory-block-in-c/52069368#52069368).  Your current method is not good at all, as it doesn't allocate the memory block in contiguous storage, doesn't check if the memory allocation fails, etc.

Comment: If you are using `cudamalloc`, there should be no need to  `malloc` anything. allocating storage is `cudamalloc`'s job. I think you may be better off explaining what the over-arching goal is. If we want to know that, we can suggest how to get you there.

Comment: @SachinBankar It depends what the actual problem is, which I don't know. You say you want to allocate memory using `malloc` for a three dimensional away (which you can't do) but you don't say *why* you want to do that. You have to tell us the problem you're trying to solve -- just telling us your proposed solution to it is not sufficient.