# Freeing The Memory of a Vector of Vector Pointers of Object Pointer Pointers Pointers of Object Pointers Pointers of Object Pointers [DO NOT DO THIS]

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector, delete-operator

First I dynamically allocate an object:

```
Object* someObject = new Object();
```

Then I insert the address of this pointer into a vector:

```
std::vector<Object**> someVector0;
someVector0.push_back(&someObject);
```

Then I insert the address of an address living in `someVector0` to another vector:

```
std::vector<Object***> someVector1;
someVector1.push_back(&someVector0[0]);
```

Lastly, I insert the address of the aforementioned `someVector1` to another vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Object***>*> someVector2;
someVector2.push_back(&someVector1);
```

Then I use the vector obtained, now I need to free the memory allocated:

```
//Do some stuff

//Free memory
```

```
    for (int i = 0; i < someVector2.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*someVector2[i]).size(); j++) {
            delete *(*(*someVector2[i])[j]);
            delete *(*someVector2[i])[j];
            delete (*someVector2[i])[j];
        }
        delete someVector2[i];
    }
```

I had suspected that this block of code would have been enough to deallocate but, I ran into some problems whilst deallocating. I suspect that I might have dereferenced a `nullptr` but I can't think of anything else, could there be a mistake in the way I delete the pointers?

Note: This is a lightened version of a problem I encountered with a program of a larger scale, none of the previously mentioned vectors is unnecessary and I do not want to handle any copies, do not change the types of the vectors.

EDIT:

Hi, after researching more and hearing out the comments I have come to my senses and even though I do not think there is a single soul that would find my code in any way sensible I strongly urge anyone that might see this as a valid way to do anything not to do it. As a comment already stated, my attempts at a solution showed that I did not have an idea of what I was doing, so please don't do it; it's practically unmaintainable. Instead, as another comment already pointed out use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) or really be aware of what happens in your code when.

Comment: What you need is to redesign your code.

Comment: May I recommend using some more `&` symbols than `*`s in c++ code? And even more important eliminate any use of `new` and `delete`.

Comment: `std::vector<Object***> someVector1;` --  `std::vector<std::vector<Object***>*> someVector2;` -- This is unmaintainable.  It seems you are trying to write code to defeat the whole purpose of using `vector`.

Comment: You only `new`ed the object pointed to by `someObject`, so that's the only object you need to `delete`.  Remember, you don't `delete` pointers, you `delete` the objects they point to, and you only need to `delete` objects you create with `new`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<Object***>*>` -- This maybe the first time I have seen a 4-star programmer.  Note that addding more stars doesn't mean it makes the code better or "advanced" or "smarter", or even faster.  It does the opposite.

Comment: Vectors of pointers a often a bad idea, but your code is worse, you allocate an object and then insert a pointer to the variable containing a pointer to the allocated object into the vector. This is **almost certainly** a mistake, and there is no right way to write this code. It gets even worse after that. However you haven't provided enough context to be sure. I don't think your problem is solvable without that context.

Comment: It must be said that your attempt at a solution shows you have no idea what you are doing, so I'm not sure why you are so convinced that all these pointers are necessary or beneficial.

Comment: I doubt that all those pointers are valid by the time you get to deleting, even if you managed to get them in the right place.

Comment: Why are you calling `new` manually at all? Use smart pointers and forget about all this.

Comment: Is the whole point of this code essentially attempting to store a 3 dimensional `Object` array inside a vector, and that the object "array" is of the form `Object***` using `new[]` to create this array?  If so, then if you *had* to do this, doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068410/allocating-a-large-memory-block-in-c/52069368#52069368) would be a lot cleaner.  Then all you would need is `std::vector<Array3D<Object>>`.

Comment: For the sake of the next person to modify this code, please see [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you should redesign your code because it is very confusing and unclear.

As each object of the type `Object` was dynamically allocated only once then for each operator `new` you need to call only one operator `delete`,

Here is a demonstration program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Object
{
    int i;
    ~Object()
    {
        std::cout << "deleting object " << i << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object **> someVector;
    Object *p_obj1 = new Object{ 1 };
    Object *p_obj2 = new Object{ 2 };

    someVector.push_back( &p_obj1 );
    someVector.push_back( &p_obj2 );

    std::vector<Object ***> someVector1;

    for (auto &p : someVector)
    {
        someVector1.push_back( &p );
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<Object ***> *> someVector2;
    someVector2.push_back( &someVector1 );

    for (const auto p_vector1 : someVector2)
    {
        for (auto ppp : *p_vector1)
        {
            delete **ppp;
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
deleting object 1
deleting object 2
```

As the vector someVector2 contains pointers to vectors then this range based for loop

```
    for (const auto p_vector1 : someVector2)
```

provides each element of the pointer type `std::vector<Object ***> *` stored in the vector.

Dereferencing the pointers in this range based for loop

```
        for (auto ppp : *p_vector1)
```

you will get elements of the pointer type `Object ***`. So to free an object of the type Object you need to get a pointer to it by two times dereferencing the elements

```
delete **ppp;
```

Answer (score 5):

For a single element, you called `new` once but `delete` 4 times.  That's wrong.  You can only `delete` something you created with `new`, and once it's deleted you cannot delete it again.